# Save data with application.current.properties

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I log in via the native app and save the data in the application.current.properties, with the following code:

```
Application.Current.Properties["Utente"] = App.UTENTE;
            Application.Current.Properties["Token"] = App.TOKEN;
```

Once the debug is closed, I try to recall the data with the following code to skip the login procedure, but it doesn't give me any results

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("Username"))
        {
            UTENTE = Application.Current.Properties["Username"].ToString();
            TOKEN = Application.Current.Properties["Token"].ToString();
            DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new MainPageLogin();
        }
```

Comment: Do you call `await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();`?

Comment: no, now I try and let you know

Comment: You are checking if there is a Username property, but did you save it?

Comment: does it have to be asynchronous?

Comment: Yep, no non-async method provided according to MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: ok, I managed to save, but I have problems deleting the data when I log out

Comment: Set each property you wish to "clear" with empty string before logging out: `Application.Current.Properties["Utente"] = "";`. Don't forget to save them. And then proceed logout.

Comment: you saved me, thank you very much